# I have a problem in my svg on phone dimensions , is there anys solutions?

Tags: css, reactjs

Half of my svg img doesn't appear in phone dimensions (check the image).[big screen][1]
The people in the image don't appear in small screen and there is no style in my css related to it.
So this the problem I have I tried many solutions like z-index and more and they didn't work
hope you can help me.

````
  position: absolute;
  left: 13%;
  top: 11%;
  height: 80%;
  width: 75%;
  z-index: 3; 
} 

#right-wheel,
#left-wheel {
  animation: wheel 15s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
//wheel is animation name
```[small screen][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U2EB.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyjcC.png
````

Answer (score 0):

For the main SVG tag, you can put max-width:100%; I think I will work. You can try it once

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).